# Revenue Growth in Oracle for Quarter 1 vs Quarter 2

Tags: oracle

Calculating Revenue Growth in Oracle for Quarter 1 vs Quarter 2 -> 
I have a sales table with columns of dt_invoice_date, sale value. I used this self-join query-

```sql
select
  yr1,qtr2, qtr1, sales1,sales2, (sales1-sales2)/sales2*100 as growth
from (
  select
   extract(year from dt_invoice_date) yr1,
   TRUNC(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dt_invoice_date) / 3) qtr1,
   sum(sale_value) as sales1
  from base_sales_data_tbl  
  group by extract(year from dt_invoice_date),
        TRUNC(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dt_invoice_date) / 3)
) S1
left outer join
 (
   select
    extract(year from dt_invoice_date)  yr2, 
    TRUNC(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dt_invoice_date) / 3) qtr2,
    sum(sale_value) as sales2
   from base_sales_data_tbl 
   group by extract(year from dt_invoice_date),
         TRUNC(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dt_invoice_date) / 3)
) S2 ON (yr1 = yr2 AND qtr2-1 = qtr1)
where qtr1= 1 and qtr2= 2
order by yr1;
```

Now, this is giving me the answer but it takes time. So, I tried to use the recursive query ->

```sql
   with s1 as (
      select
         sum(s.sale_value) sales,
         to_char(dt_invoice_date,'yyyyq') yrq, 
         lag(sum(s.sale_value),1) over (order by to_char(dt_invoice_date,'yyyyq')) sales_pq
      from base_sales_data_tbl s
      where to_char (dt_invoice_date,'q') <3 
      group by to_char(dt_invoice_date,'yyyyq')
  )
  select
     yrq,
     lag(yrq,1) over (order by yrq) prev_q,
     sales, sales_pq, round((sales-sales_pq)*100/sales_pq,2) growth
  from s1
  order by yrq;
```

But the result that I am getting is something like this

[image]

Here I want to compare the qtr1 vs qtr 2 revenue in same year. This query is giving me the revenue growth for 2015 Qtr 1 vs 2014 Qtr 2 also which I don't require. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily filter data from your result, comparing yearq and prev_q, but there is also pivot which makes all for you:

```
select yr, q1, q2, q2/q1 - 1 as growth
  from (select sale_value, to_char(dt_invoice_date, 'yyyy') yr, to_char(dt_invoice_date, 'q') q 
          from base_sales_data_tbl 
          where to_char(dt_invoice_date, 'q') < 3)
  pivot (sum(sale_value) for q in (1 q1, 2 q2))
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9d49c408d5dd94bfecd2211e525c76f1)</sup>**

Comment: Thanks !! It worked. Can you briefly explain how does this code work and how is the pivot helping in calculating the sale value from previous quarter??

Comment: It's a basic `pivot` query. Whole problem was to prepare your data correctly, where every row gets year and quarter in different columns (as you did), pivot groups data and puts values in specified columns. Description and examples: [Oracle/PLSQL: PIVOT Clause](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php). You marked non working solution as accepted, so good luck.

Comment: I have marked your answer as well. That answer worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very small mistake.

You need to use `partition by` clause in `lag` function.

Something like this:

```
lag(sum(s.sale_value),1) over (partition by trunc(dt_invoice_date,'YEAR') order by to_char(dt_invoice_date,'yyyyq')) sales_pq
```

And use the same in `group by` clause.

```
group by trunc(dt_invoice_date,'YEAR'),
 to_char(dt_invoice_date,'yyyyq'))
```

Cheers!!

Comment: I am still getting those rows, although the sale value is null but I don't wish to see the rows for '2015 Qtr1 vs 2014 Qtr1' and so on.